# I am getting error while uploading customer in magento

Tags: magento

when importing customer into magento (magento 1.2.0.0) I dnt get any error when i upload the following data with other magento customer data.

It seems magento usually skip this raw. But when i only put the following rows then i got error Email is not specific.

_address_middlename,firstname,lastname,email,password_hash,middlename,_address_firstname,_address_lastname,_address_street,_address_postcode,_address_city,_address_country_id,_address_region,_address_telephone,created_at,_website,_store,created_in,group_id,reward_update_notification,reward_warning_notification

25422:25566:1800wc,nelsdon,carddona,test@yahoo.com,nelcar082,,Elizabeth,Pollack,2512 Candle Ridge Drive,21702,Frederick,US,Maryland,301-695-8390, X307,2006-03-22 18:47:00,base,default,"Default Store View",1,0,0

anyone can give me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this:

[Magento Email validation on Customer Import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757710/magento-email-validation-on-customer-import)

Then be sure to examine whether or not `test@yahoo.com` is a valid e-mail according to the Zend e-mail validator in `/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Customer.php` as the link above indicates.